# If a wavefunction is normalized at $(x,t)$, is it also normalized at $(x\!-\!ct,t)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

If $\Bigl( \Psi(x,t),\Psi(x,t) \Bigr) =1$, I want to find out if $\Bigl( \Psi(x-ct,t),\Psi(x-ct,t) \Bigr) =1$.

My attempt was

$\Bigl( \Psi(x-ct,t),\Psi(x-ct,t) \Bigr) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x-ct,t)|^2dx$,

taking $u=x-ct$ and $dx=du+cdt$,

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x-ct,t)|^2dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(u,t)|^2du+c\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(u,t)|^2dt=1+c\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(u,t)|^2dt$.

But I'm not sure about how to calculate the last integral, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(u,t)|^2dt$...

How could these be done?

Comment: As your calculation shows, if the function $\psi(x, t)$ Is normalized, the function $\psi(x-ct, t)$ need not be. (What you actually want to show is that the function $\psi(x, t - t_0)$ is normalized.)

Comment: There is an error. The correct statement is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x-ct,t)|^2dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(u,t)|^2du$. As you integrate over all of space a shift of origin by $ct$ does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalar product means integration over $x$. The normalization at the time $t$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left| \Psi(x,t) \right|^2 dx =1
$$
Notice that the integral is over $x$ **at fixed $t$**.
The normalization  of $\Psi(x-ct,t)$ means that integration over the space has to be done again at fixed $t$. Therefore, the change of variable is ok, but it does not imply that there is an additional integration over time. $ct$ acts as a fixed translation in the space.

Comment: I see, thanks. But if we would want, for instance, to calculate the expectation value of the position, $<x>$, whit the $\Psi(x-ct,t)$ wave function, it would be also in these case an integral over x at fixed $t$?

Comment: @Quaerendo  Yes, sure. The square modulus of the wavefunction at a given time $t$ is the probability distribution at the same time and averages are evaluated at that time. Then, the unitary evolution ensures that if the wavefunction is normalized at time $t$ it will remain normalized at any other time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer as I am not sure your substitution step is justified, since you are leaving the second argument $t$ unaffected...

... but any wavefunction in quantum mechanics$^*$ obeys the Schrödinger equation, which results in *unitary* evolution.

This preserves the norm, hence:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\langle \Psi_t | \Psi_t \rangle = 0. $$

So you just have to normalise it at some initial  condition $t_0$, and it will stay normalised.

—————

$^*$ = not subject to measurements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no law of norm conservation. However, if the normalisation changes over time this in general means that energy, momentum, charge etc are not conserved. For an isated system conservation is required and the norm should be conserved.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately the schrödinger equation has the property that it automatically preserves the normalisation of the wave function.
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\Psi(x,t)|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi(x,t)|^2dx$$
[image: picture from Griffith's introduction to Quantum mechanics]
From here it must be clear that a wave function once normalised is forever normalised.
Note that this is not true for decaying particles whose total probability of finding it decreases with time.